# Store php variable in table on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to make a dynamic data but store on mysql table. That variable is save on mysql record table.

example mysql Record

```
id|message|
1 |Hi, you already register with this date $dtm|
```

After that i want to extract that data and use $dtm data for variable that declare on a controller

Model

```
public function createScheduleNotification() {
        $query = $this->db->query('select * from master_notif where message_id = 16');

        return $query->result_array();  
    }
```

Controller

```
public function abc() {
$dtm = '2016-11-10';

  $r = $this->myModel->createScheduleNotification();
  foreach ($r as $result) {
  echo $result['message'];
 }
}
```

My data on mysql table

```
message field : Hi, you already register with this date $dtm
```

so i want to take variable inside controller and put a variable inside mysql, and result will be

```
message field : Hi, you already register with this date 2016-11-10
```

Comment: why put minus rating on my questions, is it confusing ?

Comment: your Question is not clear please make edits and then we will able to answer

Comment: hahahah bro you can't save php variable in data base you need to store the actual data in data variable is work on server side not in database

Comment: if you want to get data from variable and store it on database then that will work...

Comment: hi @Yaseen i just search and it's possible using this eval function in php

Comment: yeah you can store data in variable but that variable you can't store in database if you do you never get the value again. you need to store the value of variable. not the variable.

Comment: @Yaseen : i've been put my answer in below, it possible to put variable in the table, and extract with my below answer

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$dtm = "Hi, you already register with this date '.$start.'";
```

or

```
$dtm = "Hi, you already register with this date '".$start."'";
```

Comment: Hi @Kazi Nayem that variable is store on table, how to extract it and use variable inside the table

Answer (score 0):

it is works using this

```
public function abc() {
$dtm = '2016-11-10';

  $r = $this->myModel->createScheduleNotification();
  foreach ($r as $result) {
  $res = $result['message'];
  eval("\$res = \"$res\";");
  echo $res;
 }
}
```

Comment: can you print the $r array i want to see the output